# Setting the date in date field sets it with one day before

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, date

I am using the date input type to display/get dates from a form in HTML:

```
<input type="date">
```

To set the date from JavaScript I do:

```
myInput.valueAsDate = new Date();
```

This works fine. But if I want to set another date object, for example:

```
myInput.valueAsDate = new Date(1995, 0, 1);
```

It displays `12/31/1994`–which is exaclty one day before the 1995 New Year eve. If I add `24` as hours argument, the date is displayed correctly, but the date object itself is obviously *2<sup>nd</sup> of January, 1995*, which is not a good solution to this problem.

> [image]

```js
console.log(myInput.valueAsDate = new Date(1995, 0, 1));
console.log(myInput.valueAsDate);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="myInput">
```

I get this in the console:

```
Sun Jan 01 1995 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
Sat Dec 31 1994 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
```

Is this a browser issue? Are there any workarounds/solutions?

And finally, I do *not* want to use any plugin to display/get the dates but I want to use the natative date `input`  element (at least, the question is about it `:-)`).

I reproduced this in Chromium and Chrome. Firefox seems not to support the date type inputs *yet*.

Comment: It appears to be working for me on Chrome. I see 01/01/1995

Comment: @DrewDahlman Hmm, what version?

Comment: Version 45.0.2454.101

Comment: @DrewDahlman Oh, looks like it was fixed. I'm using 45.0.2454.85. Post an answer, then! `:-)` If you find the issue in Chromium, I would appreciate it even more. :)

Comment: I also use 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit) but I still have the issue in the question. :-)

Comment: Ohhhh, OK! So, @DrewDahlman what OS are you using? Me and Silviu are using Ubuntu.

Comment: I have a hypothesis: Your profile says you are in Romania. Upon testing, it looks like `new Date(...)` creates a new object with the given time *in your current* time zone. Midnight January 1, 1995 was still 12/31/94 in UTC. Could Chrome be mishandling that?

Comment: valueAsDate property is actually a Date without a specific timezone. It binds itself with your local GMT, so the result might be different for different users coming from different timezones.

Comment: Oh, good points. Toby posted an interesting answer.

Comment: That is actually really interesting about the timezone thing. good to know!

Comment: @Manu—"*your local GMT*"? Local and GMT are different things except for those whose offset is +0.

Comment: @RobG pardon me, meant local timezone back then :) digging a comment out from 2015 :)) it's clear from the rest of the message..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the timezone difference read [this](https://austinfrance.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/html5-date-input-field-and-valueasdate-timezone-gotcha-3/).

Apparently when using `new Date()` you use the current time zone and `valueAsDate` takes a GMT `dateTime`

Changing you code to something like this

```
console.log(myInput.valueAsDate = new Date(1995, 0, 1,12));
```

should work

**Update 1**

```
console.log(myInput.valueAsDate = new Date(Date.UTC(1995, 0, 1));
```

Should work on all timezones.

Comment: Oh, good point! For posterity, could you post a reference how to transform a date in GMT date time?

Comment: Also, is there any way to ignore the timezone somehow? I would like to just display the date from the date object.

Comment: Will `new Date(1995, 0, 1,12)` work over the globe in all timezones?

Comment: @IonicăBizău i don't think you can ignore the timezones. But if you create it with just `new Date()` your users will get their current date which is ok. If you get it from a server and you site is global you should care about timezones. so it's working as expected and maybe you shouldn't be searching for a workaround.

Comment: I guess the `Date.UTC` thingy is a nice solution. Thanks. :)